# How can i retrieve last inserted value from a column of a table in DB2?

Tags: db2

I have a request_t table that contain reg_number column and that column contains values. could anyone help how to retrieve last inserted value of column? (My Database is DB2)

Comment: I suggest you use an auto-increment technical-id and use the max-function over all records to get the last inserted record.

Comment: How do you define _last_?

Comment: @mirco.widmer - I dislike using auto-increment ids that way, as I consider them to be little more than memory addresses.  That, and it's not always safe to use just `MAX()` in a concurrent environment.  @Venugopal - there's `NEW_TABLE`, which means you can get the rows you just inserted (in the same statement).  Otherwise, you usually want a timestamp to be able to get the last chronological record.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function as follows

```
SELECT ID, NAME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS ROWNUM FROM YOUR_SCHEMA.YOUR_TABLE
ORDER BY ROWNUM DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Comment: False.  Without an `ORDER BY`, that's going to give you whatever row the db can return fastest.  This will vary by what the load is, what indices you have...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - I did add `ORDER BY ROWNUM`. Although I do agree that it may return whatever the DB can return fastest based on a lot of factors. I thought the latest written record would be the fastest one to be retrieved and hence I provided that solution. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: No, without an `ORDER BY` _inside_ the `OVER` clause, the results of `ROW_NUMBER()` **itself** are random.    If you don't specify ordering over relevant base columns, there is no way to tell what you're going to get, especially because dbs are often geared to use parallel I/O.  (In this specific instance, you have a slightly higher chance of getting the correct results, as you're likely to force a complete table scan because of how you asked for the results.  Depending on some other things this could lock the table for a while, and will consume more resources than necessary.)